# Retrieving a lot url addresses

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping

Edit: Just for clarification I am using python, and would like to do this within python.

I am in the middle of collecting data for a research project at our university. Basically I need to scrape a lot of information from a website that monitors the European Parliament. Here is an example of how the url of one site looks like:

http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=REPORT&mode=XML&reference=A7-2010-0190&language=EN

The numbers after the reference part of the address refers to:
              A7 = Parliament in session (previous parliaments are A6 etc.),
              2010 = year,
              0190 = number of the file.

What I want to do is to create a variable that has all the urls for different parliaments, so I can loop over this variable and scrape the information from the websites.

P.S: I have tried this:

```
number = range(1,190,1) 

   for i in number: 
       search_url = "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=REPORT&mode=XML&reference=A7-2010-" + str(number[i]) +"&language=EN" 

      results = search_url 
      print results
```

but this gives me the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 7, in 
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to be able to loop over the parliments?

i.e. you want A7, A6, A5...?

If that's what you want a simple loop could handle it:

```
for p in xrange(7,0, -1):
    parliment = "A%d" % p
    print p
```

for the other values similar loops would work just as well:

```
for year in xrange(2010, 2000, -1):
    print year

for filenum in xrange(100,200):
    fnum = "%.4d" % filenum
    print fnum
```

You could easily nest your loops in the proper order to generate the combination(s) you need. HTH!

Edit:

String formatting is super useful, and here's how you can do it with your example:

```
# Just create a string with the format specifier in it: %.4d - a [d]ecimal with a
# precision/width of 4 - so instead of 3 you'll get 0003
search_url = "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=REPORT&mode=XML&reference=A7-2010-%.4d&language=EN"

# This creates a Python generator. They're super powerful and fun to use,
# and you can iterate over them, just like a collection.
# 1 is the default step, so no need for it in this case
for number in xrange(1,190):   
    print search_url % number
```

[String formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) takes a string with a variety of specifiers - you'll recognize them because they have % in them - followed by % and a tuple containing the arguments to the format string.

If you want to add the year and parliment, change the string to this:
`search_url = "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=REPORT&mode=XML&reference=A%d-%d-%.4d&language=EN"`

where the important changes are here: 
reference=A`%d`-`%d`-`%.4d`&language=EN

That means you'll need to pass 3 decimals like so:

`print search_url % (parliment, year, number)`

Comment: add the backtick `\`` character around it and you can write `code stuff`. I'll edit my answer to respond to that particular issue

Comment: number = range(1,190,1) 

for i in number: 
search_url = "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=REPORT&mode=XML&reference=A7-2010-"+number[i]+"&language=EN" 

results = search_url print results

Comment: Thanks alot Wayne, I could not figure out the code part for the comments so I added it to the question. But I see you were faster than me :)

This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use python and wget ?  Loop through the sessions that exist, and create a string to give to wget?  Or is that overkill?

Comment: I am using python(still learning), but I have no idea what wget is. Preferrably I would like to keep it as simple as possible...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't give this as a comment, but I don't have a high enough score yet.

Looking at the code you quoted in the comment above, your problem is you are trying to add a string and an integer.  While some languages will do on the fly conversion (useful when it works but confusing when it doesn't), you have to explicitly convert it with `str()`.

It should be something like:

`"http://firstpartofurl" + str(number[i]) + "restofurl"`

or, you can use string formatting (using `%` etc. as Wayne's answer).

Comment: Thanks Neil! After some googling I realized the mistake, I am still learning the basics :)

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium. Since it controls uses a real browser, it can handle sites using complex javascript. Many language bindings are available, including python.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no clue about selenium, and I would like to do this from within Python (as it is the only language I am somewhat familiar with).

Comment: It is well documented and I do use it from within python.